# How do you read in and compare strings in scheme?

Tags: scheme

It's obviously not done yet, but what I'm trying to do is take input from the user and search through either the number or the string that's in a list. 
It works fine if I only use numbers, but fails if I use a string.
How can I make this work?

Thank you.

My code is failing with

```
Enter student name or ID : damien
. . string=?: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: damien
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   damien
```

the part that's causing the problem has a carret pointing at it

```
(define (student l s)
  (cond 
    ((and (number? s) (= (car (car l)) s))
     (newline)
     (display "ID=")(display (car (car l)))
     (display ", Name=")(display (car (cdr (car l))))
     (display ", Grade=")(display (car (cdr (cdr (car l)))))
     (newline)
     )
   ->((string=? (car (cdr (car l))) s)
     (newline)
     (display "ID=")(display (car (car l)))
     (display ", Name=")(display (car (cdr (car l))))
     (display ", Grade=")(display (car (cdr (cdr (car l)))))
     (newline)
     )
    ((null? l) (display "Student not found")(newline))
    )
  )
(define (display-student l) 
  (display "Enter student name or ID : ")
  (student l (read))
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

`read` reads list structure and everything just like the source code of scheme looks. Thus `read` will read a string if it's enclosed with double quotes. Without it it will think it's a `symbol`. Perhaps `read-line` would be more suitable for a generic string input?

Comment: I need it to match a specific format, but you solved my problem.  symbol=? works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by specific format? `read-line` reads a string, like "Hello World" but of course without the quotes. `display` will display it without quotes, but to get the same as a symbol user needs to enter |Hello World| when it is read as a symbol. ei. not all chars are allowed in symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you did with the first clause of your `cond` (which was invoke `number?`), you need to do the same for the second clause:

Replace `(string=? ...)` with

```
(and (string? (car (cdr (car l))))
     (string? s)
     (string=? (car (cdr (car l))) s))
```

After you do that, other errors might occur, but you'll be able to continue.  For example, the `read` function will return a `symbol?` if the user just types a name (w/o quotes).  But if the user types two names, like 'Ron Paul', as first + last, then you'll get an unexpected result.